# Pandas duplicate row based on condition and unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, row

I have a pandas data frame of the following form:

```
  Name    Age    BMoney    BTime    BEffort

  John    22       1         0        0
  Pete    54       0         1        0
  Lisa    26       0         1        1
```

And I would like to convert it to

```
  Name    Age    B

  John    22     Money
  Pete    54     Time
  Lisa    26     Effort
  Lisa    26     Time
```

That is, based on the values in the "Breason" column I would like to create a new column "B" containing "reason". If for a person multiple reasons exists (i.e: a row contains multiple 1's) I would like to create seperate rows for that person in my new dataframe showcasing their different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

With Multi Index and stack():

```
# Create the dataframe
df = [["John",    22,       1,         0,        0],
      ["Pete",   54,       0,         1,        0],
      ["Lisa",    26,       1,         1,        0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["Name", "Age", "BMoney", "BTime", "BEffort"])

# Set Multi Indexing
df.set_index(["Name", "Age"], inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
# Use the fact that columns and Series can carry names and use stack to do the transformation
df.columns.name = "B"
df = df.stack()
df.name = "value"
df = df.reset_index()
```

[image]

```
# Select only the "valid" rows, remove the last columns and remove first letter in B columns
df = df[df.value == 1]
df.drop("value", axis=1, inplace=True)
df["B"] = df.B.apply(lambda x: x[1:])
```

[image]